# Is it valid to have base class attribute even though it is virtual when downcasting is done

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Please refer to below code:

```
#define mPtr (static_cast<Dog*> (new(Animal)))

class Animal{
    public:
    virtual void talk(){cout<<"A";}
};
class Dog:public Animal{
    int test;
    public:
    void talk(){bark();}
    void bark(){
        test=0;cout<<test;
    }
};

int main() {

    mPtr->talk();
    mPtr->bark();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A0
```

Is it valid or an undefined behaviour to have base class talk() is executing?

Comment: Any interesting use of `mPtr` is UB because you use `Dog` members on an `Animal` and an `Animal` is not a `Dog`.

Comment: That blatant disregard for object leakage is making me ill

Comment: As per output, I assumed that upon static down-casting, The Animal object will add up Dog property with it, keeping base functionality (talk) as it is

Comment: @StoryTeller It is a common practice for C program not to release memory when one know that the program is short lived. Whatsoever at program termination the kernel will release all the memory.

Comment: @Oliv - Aha, and yet when novices learn to get in the habit of it, they start being less worried about resources the OS won't free. This is a terrible habit to endorse in learners. No need to teach me about common practices or how OS's work.

Comment: @StoryTeller Be sure that I know it since I could enjoy your knowledge since I am on SO. But it is more a question about phylosophie. I think that applying rules blindly make us slaves while understanding them make us free. So why should we turn student into slaves?

Comment: @Oliv - I don't think we should hoard knowledge, by any means (heck, why be on SO otherwise). But I think that certain things are better revealed after the students knowledge is mature enough. Since you brought up C, "goto's considered harmful" dogma prevented me from making messes while I was only starting . When I was mature enough, I was able to appreciate when it can be used effectively to *improve* code. I don't think the OP is there yet.

Comment: I cant understand where it is going but, I have observed this use-case in a matured  QT application which I cant detail here

Comment: @ceasif - Qt works with an object model that is pretty much built over the regular C++ object model. They go to great pains in order to make sure code like yours isn't really leaking. But just because Qt types can do that, doesn't mean it's something that's good C++ in general.

Answer (score 6):

It is straight undefined behavior. You can only cast to derived class using `static_cast` when you are 100% sure that pointer points to the object of that derived class. For safe conversion in class hierarchy `dynamic_cast` can be used instead. And in this case `dynamic_cast<Dog*>(new Animal)` would return `nullptr` indicating that object pointed to is not of `Dog` class.

Comment: As per output, I assumed that upon static down-casting, The Animal object will add up Dog property with it, keeping base functionality (talk) as it is

Comment: An object is what it is. You asked for a non-specific Animal, and that's what the language gave you. Casting doesn't change the underlying object, it just changes your _view_ on it. If you want a Dog, create one of those in the first place.

Comment: @ceasif Unfortunately `static_cast` does not anyhow alter object pointed to. By using `static_cast` you are basically telling compiler "assume that this pointer points to the object of Dog class".

Comment: @ceasif - [Here's a modified version of your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4568aaed787660e6), based on Useless's answer. Why does it segfault if the property is "just added"?

Comment: Say your Animal represents a shrew, since that's a pretty early mammal. Your cast just puts a Dog costume on it, but it still can't bark, because it's really a shrew.

Comment: So, object successfully barking in example is not assured behaviour

Comment: @ceasif Getting expected results is not an indicator of absence of Undefined Behavior. You somehow manage to dodge the bullet, however this program flaw [can manifest itself with minor adjustments](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jKBllaLITq9EI9SH) (or even without them).

Comment: Let go of observed behaviour. C++ will let you do lots of nonsensical things, and undefined behaviour may sometimes appear to work. You can either write code that is correct, or spend your time memorizing hacks that sometimes work on a specific compiler but may break at any time.

Answer (score 3):

Come on, let's unpack that code and show why it is wrong. Hiding your sins in a macro doesn't make them go away.

```
int main() {
    Animal a;
    Dog *dog = &a;
    dog->talk();
}
```

Try that. Does it compile? If not, what does the compiler say? If the compiler says that assignment doesn't make sense, why would it be a good idea to coerce it?

The only case where downcasting is safe is where you *know* the dynamic type is correct (from context, or by using `typeid` or something else), or where you use `dynamic_cast` to test whether or not your object has the expected subtype.

Your un-checked downcast to the wrong subtype is indeed undefined behaviour.

---

OK, I see the confusion is actually about what `static_cast` means, rather than about polymorphism. So, let's look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

```
static_cast < new_type > ( expression )
```

Your code (downcasting) is the second case described:

> 2) If new_type is a pointer or reference to some class D and the type of expression is a pointer or reference to its non-virtual base B, static_cast performs a downcast. ... **Such static_cast makes no runtime checks to ensure that the object's runtime type is actually D**, and may only be used safely if this precondition is guaranteed by other means

The **bold** part (my formatting) is the reason your cast is illegal.

It's useful to note that this is only the case because you're casting a pointer (although it's the same for references) - the pointer is not the object. Casting a pointer doesn't alter the object or create a new one, it just provides a different view on the existing object.

Conversely, see the first case described:

> 1) If there is an implicit conversion sequence from expression to new_type, or if overload resolution for a direct initialization of an object or reference of type new_type from expression would find at least one viable function, then `static_cast<new_type>(expression)` returns the imaginary variable `Temp` initialized as if by `new_type Temp(expression);`

So, if you added a constructor

```
Dog::Dog(Animal const &) {}
```

which creates a Dog *from* an Animal, you could write

```
Animal a;
Dog dog = static_cast<Dog&>(a);
```

and it would be fine - this creates a Dog from `a` (which is *not the same object as `a`*).